# Kendo grid prevent server side filtering?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I have simple Kendo-Grid configuration as below (Mvc project)

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ReviewModel>()
      .Name("grid")
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Custom()
          .PageSize(20)
          .Schema(schema => schema.Model(m => m.Id(p => p.Id)))
          .Transport(transport =>
          {
              transport.Read("ReadData");
          })
       )   .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(m => m.Id).Visible(false);
      columns.Bound(m => m.Code).Width(110).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell =>
      {
          cell.Operator("contains");
          cell.ShowOperators(false);
      }));
      columns.Bound(m => m.Name).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell =>
      {
          cell.Operator("contains");
          cell.ShowOperators(false);
      }));})
  .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
  .Pageable(p => p.Enabled(true).Info(false).Input(true).Numeric(false)))
```

Also do little ajax call for loading data

```
function ReadData(options) {
    var option = {
        url: '/read',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {

            id: '44',
            type: '5'

        }
    };

    $.ajax(option).success(function (data) {
        options.success(data);
    }).error(function (e) {
        console.debug(e);
        options.error(e);
    });


}
```

As result everything work perfectly. grid loaded on page(Mvc partial), and then get data from server(Mvc action) and show it well.

> But for first time (in each column) if user change filter of column grid call read again, and ajax call occurred. I want to prevent to call server for filtering or other things? is that possible?

Comment: Does explicitly setting .ServerFiltering(false) on the custom DataSource change anything?

Comment: @The Dread Pirate Stephen, no even with that option ReadData trigger ajax call !

Comment: .ServerFiltering(false) doesn't work. so i find this and this link.that solution http://www.telerik.com/forums/turn-off-autocomplete-on-filter